# hexadecimal seven segment display verilog

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, 7segmentdisplay, quartus-ii

I have a 4 bit output number as output. How can it be seen on seven segment display as hexadecimal number? I'm new and mentioning verilog.

case example:

```
wire [3:0] num;
case (num)
  4'b0000 : 1111110;
  4'b0001 : 0110000;
  4'b0010 : 1101101;
  4'b0011 : 1111001;
  so on
  .
  .
  4'b1111 : 1000111;
endcase
```

[image]

4 bit binary to seven segment

```
#TABLE: x1,x2,x3,x4 => a,b,c,d,e,f,g

0000 => 1111110

0001 => 0110000

0010 => 1101101

0011 => 1111001

0100 => 0110011

0101 => 1011011

0110 => 1011111

0111 => 1110000

1000 => 1111111

1001 => 1111011

1010 => 1110111

1011 => 0011111

1100 => 1001110

1101 => 0111101

1110 => 1001111

1111 => 1000111
```

Comment: That's basically it. In verilog you just write a big `case` statement. In an FPGA it isn't really any more costly than any other way of doing it because 1) FPGA logic is done with look-up tables anyway and 2) If the number of inputs can be reduced for one or the other of the segments, your synthesis tool should take care of that optimization.

Comment: would you mind brightening some more? I've completely finished my multiplexer parts. Just I need to show them on seven segment display. I see case but what should I do? @ThePhoton

Comment: Have you looked up how to write a `case` statement in Verilog? What part don't you understand? Please edit your question to clarify what you need help with. Please don't just open up a new question asking the same thing over again.

Comment: In VHDL you can use the CASE but it's simpler to declare a constant array (Lookup table) and index it using the 4-bit number. The same must be possible in Verilog, surely?

Comment: I've edited the post. Is it right? Could you share your advises @ThePhoton

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the output value to some wire or register and then connect that net to an output pin.

Typical code (not tested) is

```
wire [3:0] num;
reg  [6:0] out;
always @num begin
    case (num):
        4'b0000 : out <= 1111110;
        4'b0001 : out <= 0110000;
        4'b0010 : out <= 1101101;
        4'b0011 : out <= 1111001;
        // ...
     endcase
end
```

Declaring `out` as a `reg` type doesn't actually make it into a register or generate a flip-flop. It just allows you to assign to `out` inside an `always` block.

Comment: If I have four fourbit number, should I write four always case? like
`always @num1 begin
    case (num1):always @num2 begin
    case (num2):always @num3 begin
    case (num3):always @num4 begin
    case (num4):`

Comment: I think the OP is asking what to do if he has four hex digits.  In that case, Instead of cutting and pasting four copies of the always block, it would be best to create a hex to seven segment module and instantiate it four times.